# how to perform filtering of nsarray in objective c

Tags: objective-c

i have a NSMutableArray which contains objects. how to perform filtering operation on it.

Answer (score 2):

1. [NSArray docs](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html)
2. search for "filter" find [`-filteredArrayUsingPredicate:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/filteredArrayUsingPredicate:)
3. ????
4. Profit!